# ¿Cómo puedo dar formato de números en Python, con separador de miles y de decimales?

Tags: python, string, conversión-de-tipos, float

En Python requiero mostrar un número con separador de miles y de decimales.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto en Python versión 3.6?

Ejemplo:

```
radio = str(input('Introduzca el radio: '))
area = float(radio) * math.pi**2
print('El area es: ' + str(area))
```

Esto si `radio` es `200` me devuelve: `1973.9208802178716`; requiero mostrar algo como esto: `1.973,92`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desde la versión 3.6 de Python puedes usar las  [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
print(f'El area es: {area:,.2f}')
```

Simplemente agregas `f` antes de la cadena de texto y los valores que quieras agregar los ingresas dentro de llaves `{}`.

Answer (score 6):

El principal problema con el que te vas a encontrar es que las rutinas de formato habituales no están localizadas. Es decir, si bien podemos formatear un numérico con separadores de miles y decimales, el de miles será la `,` (coma) y el de la parte decimal es el `.` (punto/dot). Podemos hacer esto:

```
area = 1973.9208802178716
print('El area es: {:,.2f}'.format(area))
```

Lo cual nos permite lograr esto:

```
El area es: 1,973.92
```

Nada mal, salvo que no es el formato que estás solicitando. Una forma de resolverlo sería la siguiente:

```
print('El area es: {:,.2f}'.format(area).replace(",", "@").replace(".", ",").replace("@", "."))
El area es: 1.973,92
```

Ahora simplemente intercambiando los caracteres de separación logramos el formato deseado. Esta es una solución simple y bastante cómoda.

Otra forma distinta, siempre que la configuración regional del equipo sea la adecuada, es decir el formato para la configuración de importes sea la que estás esperando, sería hacer esto:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print(locale.format('%.2f', area, grouping=True, monetary=True))
```

Usamos el módulo [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/locale.html#module-locale) y con `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` establecemos que vamos a usar la configuración default del equipo y con `locale.format()` terminamos de configurar la salida deseada.

Comment: Bien, pero el OP también pide separador de miles.

Comment: Se me escapó eso, gracias @fedorqui, ahora la edito

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta esta super cool.

Answer (score 0):

Usa `%.2f`:

```
area = 123
print('%.2f' %area)
```

Comment: ¿Y qué hay del separador de miles? Por otra parte, una pequeña explicación sería interesante

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo como sigue:

```
radio = str(input('Introduzca el radio: '))
area = float(radio) * math.pi**2
print('El area es: ' + format(area, "8.,2f"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Eso no funciona.
La respuesta sería así:

```
format(area, "8.,2f")
```