# Resultado erroneo en formula de calculo de volumen de aire de una rueda

Tags: python

A pesar de que la precedencia de los operadores creo que es correcta, hay un error que no logro divisar y que me impide llegar al  resultado correcto, que es `24090.1`.

Aquí dejo el código, si alguien puede divisar el error, le estaría muy agradecido, que vi ya varios videos y leí códigos pero no logro dar con el error.

```
print("This program compute the Volumen of space in a wheel/space")

w=185.0
a=50.0
d=14.0

print(math.pi * w**2 * a * (w * a + 2.540 * d) / 10.000000)

This program compute the Volumen or space in a wheel
4991963881.644957

#El resultado correcto deberia ser 24090.1
```

Comment: Este numero: 10.000000 es 10? porque tantos 0 como decimales?

Comment: el nro es realmente 10,000,000   el ejercicio tiene tantos ceros como los puse, solo que usa dos comas en lugar de los puntos. Aun no llego al resultado correcto, usando la calculadora llego al resultado, teniendo en cuenta la precedencia de los operadores.

Comment: 10.000000 es distinto que 10000000 porque el . Es un separador decimal... entonces sacalo y vas a estar diviendo por otro numero.. tambien, es 2540 o 2,450? No pongas puntos en los numeros salvo que quieras poner decimales!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo a [este enlace (en inglés)](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/please-answer-question-write-python-program-reads-keyboard-three-numbers-tire-computes-out-q56282787) como se habla de medidas del sistema norteamericano, se trabaja con pulgadas y las cifras se separan con coma (`,`) para los miles...

```
Las cifras en python para ser operadas van sin formato
```

En tal sentido, el código para calcular el volumen de un neumático en Estados Unidos, sería el siguiente:

```
import math

pi = math.pi # Ratio de la circunferencia dividida por su diametro
w = 185      # Ancho del neumatico en milimetros
a = 50       # Ratio de la forma del neumatico en Estados Unidos (Es un estandar en dicho país)
d = 14       # Diametro del neumatico en pulgadas

# los numeros deben ir sin separador de miles
vol = pi * ( w**2 ) * a * (w * a + 2540 * d) / 10000000 # Volumen Neumatico

# Se redondea a un decimal
# Volumen Neumatico: 24090.1
print( round(vol, 1) )
```

Como nota adicional, es recomendable nombrar las variables (w, a, d) para dar un mejor contexto de que hace la fórmula o función implementada

Comment: Muchas Gracias a los que me colaboraron,  el tema de fondo eran las comas o puntos, ahora esta mas que claro que python no usa puntos ni comas, cuenta las posiciones para diferenciar los espacios decimales . Muchas gracias Hubert y gbianchi !!

Comment: Si bien python no opera con formato los números... el resultado puede ser impreso con formato... [¿Cómo puedo dar formato de números en Python, con separador de miles y de decimales?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178990/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-dar-formato-de-n%C3%BAmeros-en-python-con-separador-de-miles-y-de-decima)

Comment: @AugustoAcha si la respuesta te fue de ayuda, puedes votar a favor y aceptarla, para más información mira [que hacer cuando alguien responde tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). De hecho, esa es la forma de agradecer en el sitio, y no comentarios.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, por ayudarme a comprender la lógica del sitio!!